# Can’t get BottomNavigationView from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, bottom-navigation-bar

I have a BottomNavigationView (and the latest JetPack Navigation Component) created in MainActivity that I need to show/hide in different Fragments according to the authentication state of the user.

Up to just a few days ago, I would just retrieve it from the Fragment with
requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.nav_view)  (not the best
practice, I realize, but it was acceptable for now).

After upgrading to Android Studio Bumblebee along with a few more Navigation libraries, that gives NullPointerException.

I then tried by using an Interface like below but still getting NPE.

I would really want to still create the bottom bar *in one place only* and be able to retrieve it from anywhere accordingly.

main_activity.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />  
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements HomeFragment.onGetBottomNavViewListener {

private ActivityMainBinding binding;
private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    bottomNavigationView = binding.navView;

    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);
}

@Override
    public void showBottomNavView() {
       bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void hideBottomNavView() {
      bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

}
```

HomeFragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_padding"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_padding"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_padding"
    android:paddingBottom="100dp">

    <LinearLayout>....</LinearLayout>

    <GridLayout>....</GridLayout>
       
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/search_btn"
        style="@style/BaseButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Go!"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/gridLayout" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
  private onGetBottomNavViewListener listener;

  public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        View root = binding.getRoot();

return root;
}

 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        ((AppCompatActivity) requireActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("");

        // If user is logged in
        if (user != null) {
             listener.showBottomNavView();
        } else {
             listener.hideBottomNavView();
        }
   }

    // INTERFACE
    public interface onGetBottomNavViewListener {
        void showBottomNavView();
        void hideBottomNavView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        // Store the listener (activity) that will have events fired once the fragment is attached
        if (context instanceof onGetBottomNavViewListener) {
            listener = (onGetBottomNavViewListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new ClassCastException(context +
                    "must implement HomeFragment.onGetBottomNavViewListener");
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: still can't get the bottomBar from the fragment but I solved this particular case by simply moving the authentication check, along with the bar managing, in the MainActivity with

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
                if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
                    navView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    navView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method for Showing and hiding the BottomNavugationView in your activity. In your fragment would just call

```
((YourActivity) requireActivity()).showBottomNavigationView()
```

or

```
((YourActivity) requireActivity()).hideBottomNavigationView()
```

Comment: How would you code that in details? Because as I see it, that's the same as I did with the interface.